# Does the following sentence make sense without using 'longer' twice?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> We will be here till the middle of April. After that, we might be here
> a little bit longer but not much.

I feel there should be 'longer' after 'much'. Does the sentence sound incomplete without 'longer'?

Comment: "Much" is understood as "much longer", so there's no need to repeat "longer".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is old hat, but I was always taught that using the same word twice in a sentence was bad practice. However you could say

> ... we might stay a little bit longer but not **by** much.

or just

> ... we might stay a little bit longer.

since *a little bit* already precludes a long stay.

Comment: I think that yes, saying the same word twice in a sentence (or really in close proximity) is seen as bad practice; probably due to it being seen as you do not know much vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds fine without the other ‘longer’. You may feel as if you have to say it twice, but due to context, I would say people will definitely know what you are talking about, and it is grammatically correct. It also makes it sound more natural.